# How to create firebase project with the same SHA-1 key as used in another project?

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to create two Firebase projects with the same SHA-1? because I have an android project created already and the installed application are targeting that project, now for some reasons I need to use another project for the newer versions of the same applications so the existence of both firebase projects is necessary.
But I wonder how would I do it with the same SHA-1 because it gives me error and I am not able to find a way?

The error message says:

> An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project

Comment: Can you tell us what's the error?

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008 this is what I get when I try to create the app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read the error message carefully.  It says it's using both the package name of the app *and* the SHA-1.  This means you can have the same SHA-1 in two projects, but the package names of the app (also called "application id") must be different.  Likewise, you can have two projects that have the same package name, but they can not have any of the same SHA-1 added to them.

The combination of package name and SHA-1 must be unique.

Comment: now the issue i am facing is that i am a new developer to the company and the old developer is not in touch. how can i find which id he has used to do this? or where is this project located?

Comment: The projects are in the drop down panel of the Firebase main page. Choose the different project and look for project settings. There you'll see in general section what SHAs were used with what package names.

Comment: issue with me is my company wants to have project & app setup on new developer account, I have both accounts but cannot create firebase project with same package & SHA1 ... is there any work around ? fyi.. app is using authentication & also google fit api in previous google cloud project

Comment: but if you change the package name it would be a complete different app. you can't upload it as an update on play store. you have to upload it as a new app

Comment: @alirezaeasazade Yes, but that has nothing to do with the way the Firebase console works.  You're free to have many app instances with same ID in Firebase.  It's up to you to figure out what you want to do with those when it comes time to publish.

Answer (score -1):

Create a copy of your project and change the project package name everywhere, and keep the Sha1 It should work.Create another project in firebase and add it.