# Delete duplicate fingerprint in OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0

Due to some error I deleted my previous project from firebase and created a new one with same SHA-1 but it shows SHA-1 is already registered in OAuth 2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create firebase project with the same SHA-1 key as used in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555189/how-to-create-firebase-project-with-the-same-sha-1-key-as-used-in-another-projec)

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase Support, a deleted project usually takes 30 days before a complete wipe out from their system. You may [restore](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en) the deleted project with the conflicting SHA-1 and delete the OAuth client manually.